# parallaxscroll view in android is not working

Tags: android, xml, parallax

Hi I am trying to achieve parallaxscrollview in my application using library from link below:-

https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll

And below is the my xml code:-

```
    <com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:inner_parallax_factor="1.9"
    app:parallax_factor="1.9"
    app:parallax_views_num="3"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_profile_summary" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LIN_First"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/REL_People"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_profile_list_item"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TXT_Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/str_txt_people"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IMG_Right_Arrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_nav_right_white" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/REL_Popular"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_profile_list_item"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TXT_TitlePopular"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/str_txt_popular"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IMG_Right_Arrow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_nav_right_white" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/REL_Official_Act"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/LIN_First"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_profile_list_item"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TXT_OfficialAccounts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/str_official_accounts"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IMG_Right_Arrow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_nav_right_white" />
            </RelativeLayout>



            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/REL_Search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/REL_Official_Act"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/EDT_Search_text"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_search_text_background"
                    android:hint="@string/str_edt_searchanything_hint"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/REL_SearchButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EDT_Search_text"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_search_btn_bg"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/BTN_Search"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_search"
                        android:padding="5dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>



            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/LST_AlbumList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/REL_Search"
                android:dividerHeight="0dip" >
            </ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>
 </com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView>
```

I am trying to achieve MultipleParallaxScrollView.

But nothing is happening.
Will anybody please explain me what to do??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by *nothing is happening.*? are you getting any error or something ?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ : I am not getting any error. No scrolling is also there. .

Comment: are you able to successfully run the demo project from that link ?

Comment: Yeah demo project is working fine, but its nit working in mine.

Comment: have you added the code in your project or just given dependency ?

Comment: I have added the code in my project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64150/discussion-between-vinay-raut-and-sweetwisher-).

Comment: @VinayRaut Please post a screenshot of your layout.

Comment: @VinayRaut Have you binded any data into your ListView?

Comment: @VinayRaut Take a look at my library if you need some ideias: https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-listview

Answer (score 1):

> You need to use *LinearLayout* as a child in *ParallaxScrollView*.

*You should place one child in ParallaxScrollView* containing the entire contents to scroll; which is a *LinearLayout*

Answer (score 0):

this problem is occurred because dependency use `implementation 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'` not working with `compileSdkVersion 27` or new sdk version,

you can salve this to download module from github and impot module in your project and update with ur project sdk version.[this is my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91IGr.png) [update library gradle sdk version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI07W.png)